# Why can't I fill this php array in while loop?

Tags: php

I'm trying to add values to an array in a while loop in php, however, I can't seem to do so. Values are added to the array if I just test with strings, but using variables doesn't work.  The variables ($array[$j][0]) can be echoed by themselves but not added to the added array.

```
while($j>0){
    $added=array();
    $added[]=$array[$j][0];
}
print_r($added);
```

Comment: `$array[$j][0]` is always empty & in every iteration you are resetting the array.

Comment: Move `$added = array();` outside of the while loop. Plus, `$j` is never incremented, and `$array[0][0]` wouldn't exist. Can you go into detail of what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Thank you! Yup was clearing the array every iteration. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Each time $added array is getting reset(empty) in while loop. Use below code

```
    $added=array();
while($j>0){
    $added[]=$array[$j][0];
}
print_r($added);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting the value of $added to equal an empty array inside your while loop. Try moving $added=array(); outside of the loop, before the while. I think you're missing part of your code snippet - but that is one issue I'm seeing.